# Reshape and adding dimension

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, conv-neural-network

I have an y_train (4D)  matrix which content is (33, 224, 224, 1) where (n_images, n_pixels_y, n_pixels_x, n_bands) that needed to be transformed into a 2D vector using Flatten

now i need to do the inverse process and turn the 2D vector back to the 4D matrix with the same dimensions.

i used np.reshape() and np.expand_dims() to get the shape (224, 224, 1) back, but i need add 'n_images' into the (n_images, 224, 224, 1) 
what is the best way to do it?

```py
train_x = np.reshape(y_test[1], (224, 224))
print(train_x.shape) #this result in (224, 224)

train = np.expand_dims(train_x, -1)
print(train.shape) #this result in (224, 224,  1)

pred = index_test
print(pred.shape) ##this result in (33,)
```

Comment: Put -1 as size to one dimension of a new shape, numpy will figure out the correct size

Comment: You can include expand in the reshape, (224,224,1)

Comment: You can't include the 33 when reshaping `y_test[1]`.  It isn't big enough.